# Get the first 5 nodes from XmlDocument

Tags: c#, rss, nodes, xmldocument

I need help getting the first five nodes from feedSource

```
        XmlDocument feedSource = FeedSource;
        if (feedSource != null)
        {
            Rss.DataSource = feedSource.SelectNodes("//item")
            Rss.DataBind();
        }
```

I've seen in other examples that i should be able to use

```
         Rss.DataSource = feedSource.SelectNodes("//item")[position() <= 5]
         Rss.DataBind();
```

but that doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "doesn't work" - it would help us help you if you explained *what* didn't work. (but I suspect a compile error in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Rss.DataSource = feedSource.SelectNodes("//item[position() <= 5]");
```

That `[]` part belongs to the XPath query, not to the C# part.

Comment: @Andy - then please mark the answer as "accepted" (the checkmark). That helps future visitors.